# Thread vs AsyncTask vs Service for interaction with UI

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am a bit confused how to choose between the `Thread`, `AsyncTask`, or `Service` to use in my app.

My use case is a metronome with a countdown timer to help users to practice some guitar chords. I have a couple of controls to play and pause the practice, and the countdown timer must update the ui as it changes.

Obviously I don't want to do the timer as well as the metronome code into the main thread, so my alternatives were:

**Thread**: I start two threads to play the metronome and the timer respectively; but it would be really painful to handle all the corner cases, and I know that there is a better solution. *(So I discarded this option)*

**AsyncTask**: It is a slightly better approach, but if I rotate the screen it starts the metronome and the timer again. Also, I have read that AsyncTask are not recommended for long running operations.

**Service**: This one seems to be the better alternative, since it is designed for long running operations. On the other hand, services should not be used to interact with the UI.

I am planning to use the **Service**, what are the drawbacks of using it interacting with the UI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The drawback is that you have to figure out a way for the Service to communicate back to the Activity that's making use of it.  Services can't interact directly with UI at all, nor should they ever.

Usually people make use of an event bus for communicating between a Service and Activity.